# How do I change yes or no to a binary classification?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I change "yes" or "no" to a 0 or 1 in a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: For anyone with the same question I found:
`df.IndexName.replace(('yes', 'no'), (1, 0), inplace=True) ` to give the best results. Other methods I tried were resulting in NaN's.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['yes','no','yes'],'b':['no','no','yes']})
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.map({'yes':1,'no':0}),axis=0)
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  0
2  1  1
```